# Test case sometimes passes sometimes fails

Tags: python

I have the below code which solves an algorithm problem

```
def apply_port_exclusions(include_ports, exclude_ports):
    nc_ports = _reduced(include_ports)
    for each in exclude_ports:
       ex_low,ex_high = each
    result = list()
    for pair in inc_ports:
       low, high = pair
       pair_range = range(low, high + 1)
       if high < ex_low or ex_high < low:
        # this pair is not excluded
        result.append(pair)
    elif ex_low <= low and ex_high >= high:
        # this pair is excluded
        continue
    if ex_low in pair_range:
        if ex_low == low:
            pass
        else:
            result.append([low, ex_low - 1])
    if ex_high in pair_range:
        if ex_high == high:
            pass
        else:
            result.append([ex_high + 1, high])
    return result
```

and here is my test case

```
class TestPortExclusions(unittest.TestCase):
def test_first_input(self):
    include_ports = [[80, 80], [22, 23], [8000, 9000]]
    exclude_ports = [8080, 8080]
    result = port_exclusions.apply_port_exclusions(
        include_ports, exclude_ports
    )
    self.assertEqual([[22, 23], [80, 80], [8000, 8079], [8081, 9000]],
                     result)

def test_second_input(self):
    include_ports = [[8000, 9000], [80, 80], [22, 23]]
    exclude_ports = [1024, 1024]
    result = port_exclusions.apply_port_exclusions(
        include_ports, exclude_ports
    )
    self.assertEqual([[22, 23], [80, 80], [8000, 9000]], result)

def test_third_input(self):
    include_ports = [[1,65535]]
    exclude_ports = [1000,2000]
    result = port_exclusions.apply_port_exclusions(
        include_ports, exclude_ports
    )
    self.assertEqual([[1, 999], [2001, 65535]], result)

def test_fourth_input(self):
    include_ports = [[1,1], [3, 65535], [2, 2]]
    exclude_ports = [500, 2500]
    result = exclude_ports.apply_port_exclusions(
        include_ports, exclude_ports
    )
    self.assertEqual([[1, 499], [2501, 65535]], result)

def test_fifth_input(self):
    include_ports = []
    exclude_ports = [8080, 8080]
    result = port_exclusions.apply_port_exclusions(
        include_ports, exclude_ports
    )
    self.assertEqual([], result)

def test_low_edge_case(self):
    include_ports = [[1, 1000]]
    exclude_ports = [1, 1]
    result = port_exclusions.apply_port_exclusions(
        include_ports, exclude_ports
    )
    self.assertEqual([[2, 1000]], result)

def test_high_edge_case(self):
    include_ports = [[1, 1000]]
    exclude_ports = [1000, 1000]
    result = port_exclusions.apply_port_exclusions(
        include_ports, exclude_ports
    )
    self.assertEqual([[1, 999]], result)


def test_reduced(self):
    result = port_exclusions._reduced([[1, 1], [2, 2]])
    self.assertEqual([[1, 2]], result)

def test_reduced_empty_list(self):
    result = port_exclusions._reduced([])
    self.assertEqual([], result)
```

However, I am this test case sometime passes sometimes not, according to the problem it is in this line

```
ex_low,ex_high = each
```

Error I am getting:

```
 Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py", line 628, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/Users/a10.12/PycharmProjects/DataStructures&Alghorithms/test_port_exclusion.py", line 44, in test_fifth_input
    include_ports, exclude_ports
  File "/Users/a10.12/PycharmProjects/DataStructures&Alghorithms/port_exclusions.py", line 4, in apply_port_exclusions
    ex_low,ex_high = each
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

How can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you have to change. It looks like you are trying to assign `ex_low` to the first value of `exclude_ports` and `ex_high` to the second. The actual `exclude_ports` in your test cases is just a list, so you don't have to use a for loop. You can instead write something like

```
ex_low, ex_high = exclude_ports[0], exclude_ports[1]
```

I noticed another error in the lines

```
for pair in inc_ports:
   low, high = pair
```

It looks like `inc_ports` is a list of lists, and the `each` in `for each in inc_ports` is a list. When you tried to assign two things, `low` and `high`, to just the one `each`, you get an error. Instead, you can do something like:

```
for each in inc_ports:
   low, high = each[0], each[1]
```

Or alternatively:

```
for x,y in inc_ports:
   low = x
   high = y
```

One more thing, it also looks like the line `elif ex_low <= low and ex_high >= high:` is supposed to be in the same indent level as `if high < ex_low or ex_high < low:`

You might wanna check the indent level for the rest of the if statements as well depending on what you meant to do.

Thanks

Comment: thank you, however if i use this ex_low, ex_high = exclude_ports[0], exclude_ports[1], it is giving me the error if high < ex_low or ex_high < low:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'